# JavaScript: Do Block Not Stopping Even When False (Unexpected Token Function)

Tags: javascript, html

[UPDATE: Go to Bottom]
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. 
I first called the function:

```
var WelcomeBreak = document.addEventListener("keypress", WelcomeFour(event));
```

Then, I initiated it:

```
function WelcomeFour(e)
{
    var x = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (x == 13) 
    {
        WelcomeAnimation = false;
    }
}
```

I saw it being done like this (or like this in a way) but when I do it, I get a "Unexpected Token Function." I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am not very familiar with what I am doing, but I am familiar enough to know how things in Javascript work. Here is the full code if you need it:

**Javascript**

```
function Start()
{
    var MainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("Main_Container")[0];
    var WelcomeParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    var WelcomeSpan = document.createElement("span");
    var WindowHalfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var WindowHalfHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var WelcomeSpanHalfWidth = 414.453 / 2;
    var WelcomeSpanHalfHeight = 120 / 2;
    var WelcomeBreak = document.addEventListener("keypress", WelcomeFour(event));
    var WelcomeAnimation = new Boolean(true);
    do
    {
        WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = 0;
        var Op1 = 0;
        var Op2 = 1;
        var foo1, foo2, foo3;
        foo1 = setInterval(WelcomeOne, 20);
        function WelcomeOne()
        {
            WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = Op1;
            Op1 = Op1 + .01;
            if (Op1 > 1)
            {
                clearInterval(foo1);
                foo2 = setTimeout(WelcomeTwo, 1000);
            }
        }
        function WelcomeTwo()
        {
            clearTimeout(foo2);
            foo3 = setInterval(WelcomeThree, 20);
        }
        function WelcomeThree()
        {
            WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = Op2;
            Op2 = Op2 - .01;
            if (Op2 < 0)
            { 
                clearInterval(foo3);
            }
        }
        WelcomeAnimation = false;
    }
    function WelcomeFour(e)
    {
        var x = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (x == 13) 
        {
            WelcomeAnimation = false;
        }
    }
    while (WelcomeAnimation == true);
    WelcomeParagraph.style.margin = "0%";
    WelcomeParagraph.style.position = "absolute";
    WelcomeParagraph.style.top = (WindowHalfHeight - WelcomeSpanHalfHeight) + "px";
    WelcomeParagraph.style.left = (WindowHalfWidth - WelcomeSpanHalfWidth) + "px";
    WelcomeSpan.style.fontSize = "100px";
    WelcomeSpan.style.fontFamily = "Roboto";
    WelcomeSpan.textContent = "Welcome";
    WelcomeParagraph.appendChild(WelcomeSpan);
    MainContainer.appendChild(WelcomeParagraph);
    window.addEventListener("resize", Resize);
    function Resize()
    {
        var WindowHalfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var WindowHalfHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
        WelcomeParagraph.style.top = (WindowHalfHeight - WelcomeSpanHalfHeight) + "px";
        WelcomeParagraph.style.left = (WindowHalfWidth - WelcomeSpanHalfWidth) + "px";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <!--
            Name:Bradley
        -->
        <link href="Game1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Game1.js"></script>
        <title>Game</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="Start()">
        <div class="Main_Container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html
{
    margin:0%;
}
body
{
    margin:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.Main_Container
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

PS: Anything suggestions you have for how I should start doing my code is GREATLY appreciate! I really want to become a better coder, so anything will help :)

Update **Javascript**
I moved the function WelcomeFour into the do block. It fixed some of the problem but not all of it. The WelcomeFour function will not stop when I press enter. I think i could make it work with `if` statements but I don't know how exactly. Here is the updated code:

```
do
{
    WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = 0;
    var Op1 = 0;
    var Op2 = 1;
    var foo1, foo2, foo3;
    foo1 = setInterval(WelcomeOne, 20);
    function WelcomeOne()
    {
        WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = Op1;
        Op1 = Op1 + .01;
        if (Op1 > 1)
        {
            clearInterval(foo1);
            foo2 = setTimeout(WelcomeTwo, 1000);
        }
    }
    function WelcomeTwo()
    {
        clearTimeout(foo2);
        foo3 = setInterval(WelcomeThree, 20);
    }
    function WelcomeThree()
    {
        WelcomeSpan.style.opacity = Op2;
        Op2 = Op2 - .01;
        if (Op2 < 0)
        { 
            clearInterval(foo3);
        }
    }
    function WelcomeFour(e)
    {
        var x = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (x == 13) 
        {
            WelcomeAnimation = false;
        }
    }
    WelcomeAnimation = false;
}
while (WelcomeAnimation == true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [`do {} while ()` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) but you omitted the `while ()` part and put the function declaration in its place.

---

> ```
> document.addEventListener("keypress", WelcomeFour(event));
> ```

You are calling `WelcomeFour` **immediately** and trying to assign its *return value* as the event listener.

Don't call it.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", WelcomeFour);
```

Comment: Where do you suggest I put it?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko — Put what?

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't Call it?"

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko — Remove the `(list of arguments)`. Pass the function itself. Seriously, I rewrote the line of code that was wrong. It's a simple matter of replacing the code I quoted with the slightly different line of code at the end of the answer.

Comment: I removed it, but the complier is saying that `function WelcomeFour(e)` line is the problem. The code is not running yet.

Comment: Your `do {} while ();` loop is missing the `while` part.

Comment: It's there. I just put it after the Welcome4 function `while (WelcomeAnimation == true);` Should it be right after the do or can it be after the do in the same function (In this case "Start")?

Comment: The `while` has to be immediately after the `do` block.

Comment: I put it inside of the do block. It fixed part of the problem. The other part is making the do block stop when enter is pressed. I read somewhere that the do block will run once regardless of whether or not it's false. If that where true, who would I fix that?

Comment: Events will be queued until the JS isn't too busy to respond to them. While it is in the loop, it will be too busy. You can't use a `while` loop if you want to interrupt it with an event. Use `setInterval` instead.

Comment: Could I use nested `if` statements?

Comment: Not to create a loop.

Comment: I think we came up with the solution. I think my problem IS the loop. I didn't want a loop in the first place. I thought it would work with what I was doing, but apparently not. I'll try `if` statements and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

`var WelcomeBreak = document.addEventListener("keypress", WelcomeFour);`

You are calling the function, `document.addEventListener` expects a callback, it just needs a reference. The way you have written the code, it executes the `WelcomeFour` function. The `event` object would be passed internally to the `WelcomeFour` function.

Function reference is the **function name** . If you use a function name it is basically referring to the function defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "a reference?" Could you put an example in your answer? I think it would help me, visually.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko — They did put an example! The same example I put in my earlier answer!

Comment: I removed it, but the code isn't working I suspect `function WelcomeFour(e)` is the problem because that's what the compiler said.